# How far south of the origin, does the line pass?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$x$ represents east

$y$ represents north

$z$ represents height above the ground

$3$ items are located on the plane :

$x+3z=-800$

There is another plane:

$14x-15y+3450z=15950$

Now the intersection of the 2 planes is the line :

$x=15t$

$y=-1136t-62396.7$

$z=-5t-266.7$

The Question says:
"How far south of the origin does the line pass?"

Now I dont understand what does the question mean when it says how far south does it pass, so I need a hint or an explanation.

P.S: The answer given is approx 62000

Comment: Perhaps, if you start at (0,0,0) and go along (0,0,-q) until you "meet" the line. Then what is the distance from the origin til the meeting point.

Comment: In the Question North-south movement is represented by the y-axis so I should use $(0,-t,0)$?

Comment: Yes, but remember that the $t$ in $(0,-t,0)$ isn't the same $t$ as in your line. So perhaps change it to $q$ or something.

Comment: I will have to set $x$ and $z$ as zero, but this way I cant get a unique value of $t$, so the line doesnt pass $(0,q,0)$

Comment: Please post the original wording of the question. As it stands, we are just guessing.

Comment: If you cant find unique $t$ then there is something wrong in the question/ how we interpret it. @h-squared

Comment: @Olba12  I editted the post

Comment: Solve $(0,-q,0) = (15t, -1136t - 62396.7, -5t - 266,7)$

Comment: @Olba12 $15t=0, t=0$, and $-5t-266.7=0, t=53.34$, So which t should I use

Comment: From row 1 and 3 you get that $t$ must equal $0$. And thus you can solve for $q$ in row 2.

Comment: A point due south from the origin has $x$ coordinate $0$ and negative $y$ coordinate. And indeed you get those conditions when $t=0.$

Comment: @DavidK But I am getting $t=53.34$ when solving the 3rd row

Comment: I think that should be $t=-53.34.$ And that is the solution for where the line meets the ground. That point is not due south from the origin. I think you are supposed to solve for $x=0$ and never mind the value of $z$.

Comment: Thats why I am confused, why do we ignore $z$ and use $x$